# Porque no me funciona el Calendar de java para horas y minutos

Tags: java, android

Mi problema es simple: porque este método no me funciona para cuando es tiempo es mayor que 30 minutos. No se exactamente si es para 30 pero para 1 hora y 30 minutos no funciona. Simplemente no entra metodo run() de la clase Temporisador que hereda de TimerTask. Pero si lo configuro para segundos si funciona.

```
public void TactivarBroucast(int a,int b) { //a y b el tiempo en horas (a) y el tiempo en minutos (b)
       long t=b*3600000+a*60000; //1s = 1000ms 1m=60000 
      Log.d("metodo",String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()+t));
       Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+t);
       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       c.setTime(date);
      // c.set(Calendar.HOUR,b);
      //   c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,(int) t);
       date = c.getTime();
       Timer time = new Timer();
       time.schedule(new Temporisador(), date);
   }
```

Las lineas que están comentareadas es porque ya lo intente y no funciono. También tengo entendido que se puede usar el AlarmManager. Como quedaría este ultimo? Cabe destacar que estoy haciendo una aplicacion de android. Como puedo hacer para programar una tarea en android para que se ejecute luego de X tiempo (horas y minutos)?Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba ser mas explicito en los nombres de tus variables

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int hora = 1;
    int mins = 30;

    final long t = (hora * 60 + mins) * 60 * 1000;

    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + t);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);

    Timer time = new Timer();
    time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Running!");
        }
    }, date);
}
```

Este código funcionó para mi, seguramente estas confundiendo la semántica de las variables **a** y **b**

**Notas:**

1. el método no debería llamarse broadCast?
2. los metodos en java, por convencion deberian iniciar con letra minuscula, ej *tActivaBroadcast()*
3. cuidado con Temporisador, tiene un error, debería ser Temporizador (esta vez si con mayúsculas por que es una clase)

Answer (score 0):

Debes de usar `add` para agregar horas/minutos a cierta fecha:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  //obtienes la fecha de este momento (now)
c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,a);      //agregas las horas(a) a la hora actual
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE,b);          //agregas los minutos(b) a la hora/minutos actual
Timer time = new Timer();
time.schedule(new Temporisador(), c.getTime());     //obtienes la fecha actualizada
```

`a` y `b` deben de ser `int`.

Comment: de perdido expliquen porque el -1?